# Speed of sound in air and Laplace's correction

Tags: thermodynamics, acoustics

Newton wrote the bulk modulus for speed of sound by writing the ideal gas law in differential form, and, laplace wrote another expression by taking writing the differential form of the adiabatic gas law.

Now what's weird for me, here, is that there are two expressions for bulk modulus?? so, which is the correct one? I know Laplace one is the right because that gives a value closer to real speed of sound but then, why are Newtons wrong?

I think that both should be right because an ideal gas in the adiabatic process follows both adiabatic law and ideal gas law. but this suggests two different expressions for bulk modulus..

Reference H.c verma concept of physics book pg-332

Comment: The question's premise is a bit wrong. Newton assumed Isothermal and Laplace assumed Adiabatic. None of them assumed air to be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Newton assumed isothermal process, and wrote the ideal gas law

$$PV=nrT$$

or, $$ P \Delta V + V \Delta P = 0 $$

and we can solve for bulk modulus which is pressure over relative change of volume

While Laplace took it as an adiabatic process, where

> $ PV^{\gamma} = C$

and he rewrote the equation as a differential equation.

Note that adiabatic does not imply an isothermal process as in, we can't write Newton's equation under Laplace's assumption because temperature would not differentiate to zero.